# Rename millions of files on Linux

Tags: linux, rename

I need to rename about 2 million images. 
The files look like this `image.jpg?arg=value` and need to be renamed to `image.jpg` without the arguments.

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
sudo find . -name "*.jpg?*" -exec rename 's/(\?.*)//' {} \;
```

This gets the job done but seems to take forever. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to speed this up?

Comment: If there are million files, it might actually take a long time. What do you want, a progress indicator? If so, put `find` in the background, and may be you can do a `watch` on count of *.jpg files.

Comment: Didn't think of that, but that would actually be good to see. I was thinking more along the lines of parallelization.

Comment: You could also try to run one `rename` per directory instead of per file. I must admit that I don't know the syntax for that, but it would save a lot of process creation overhead.

Comment: Alternatively, write a small C program to do the job (using the [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) syscall and the [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) etc... functions), which would e.g. write something in `syslog` every 1000 renaming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try

```
sudo find . -name "*.jpg*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' -P4 -n1 rename 's/(\?.*)//' {} \;
```

From the man page of `xargs`

```
   --max-procs=max-procs
   -P max-procs
          Run  up  to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1.  If
          max-procs is 0, xargs will run as many processes as possible  at
          a  time.   Use the -n option with -P; otherwise chances are that
          only one exec will be done.
```

Here I am limiting the max child process to 4. If you want more then mark -P0 which will take max possible child, but remember, your CPU will be heavily overloaded.

**OR**

use gnu [parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: I can't actually wait to try this stuff out. If this works, its really cool! :)

Comment: You can try with a sample set.

Comment: Definitely faster, set `P0` since the system doesn't need to handle anything else currently.
Final command `sudo find . -name "*.jpg?*" -print | xargs -I '{}' -P4 -n1 rename 's/(\?.*)//' {} \;` (note the ? for the name argument)

Comment: It's recommended to use `find -print0` with `xargs -0` to avoid strange file name issues. i.e. including spaces, new lines

Answer (score 2):

parallelize the renaming. Start two (or three, four) shells and run the command. Be sure that you seperate somehow the images for the commands, so that not 2 commands are run on the same images.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this on Ubuntu 14.04 but it does not work. The command executed successfully but nothing happened. I figured that the rename regex part is not right. To check this:

```
$ echo Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png.de4Mzv2 | sed 's/(\?.*)//'
Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png.de4Mzv2
```

But changing the regex to the following works.
    $ echo Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png.de4Mzv2 | sed 's/.[^.]*$//'
    Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png

Using that in the command suggested by @realspirituals, I have the following files:

```
$ ls -ltr
Screenshot_from_2015-08-19_114601.png.somegthingy 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png.de4Mzv2 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122455.png.ac84Lk1
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_154012.png.uNl34sH 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_101459.png.53rv1ce 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_101437.png.l4Pt0pz 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_101230.png.p31Ic4n

$ sudo find . -name "*.png*" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} -P4 -n1 rename 's/\.[^\.]*$//' {} \;
Screenshot_from_2015-08-19_114601.png 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122455.png
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_154012.png 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_101459.png 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_101437.png 
Screenshot_from_2015-08-13_101230.png
```

Comment: Ah! But it does work using the regex 's/\?.*//' if the filename is as stated as the poster -- eg. Screenshot_from_2015-08-17_122834.png?arg=de4Mzv2